# Limiting mA on 9v Batteries in Series

Tags: batteries

If I am putting 6, 9v batteries in series and want to limit the mA at the leads coming off the terminals to 1-4 mA how would I achieve this goal.  The anode and cathode will be a piece of silver wire submerged in distilled water to create an emergency source of colloidal silver.  I know I don’t have to limit it to create my solution, but by doing so, limiting 1-4 mA will produce a much smaller ionic silver particle than at higher mAs.

Thanks

Comment: This is not well thought out. Why would you use a high voltage? Why use 9 V batteries which provide few mA-hr, and will be drained quickly before producing much Ag?

Comment: https://www.webmd.com/vitamins/ai/ingredientmono-779/colloidal-silver

Comment: I am wondering why one needs an "emergency source of colloidal silver". What kind of emergency requires silver mixed with water? Your dog turns out to be a werewolf so you put some in his water dish?

Comment: 3 - 9v or 6 - 9v may not be a lot of power but when I’m only trying to achieve 10 - 20ppm it should be plenty.  It’s thought out in terms of what might be available remotely in a pinch, not for efficiency.  I have been making it for 20 years with machines built with limiters, v and Amp controls.  I’m looking for an emergency field solution where you will have to make use of what you have around you.

Comment: I think, it will be necessary to use a suitable SMPS aka DC/DC converter with current output to prevent energy from being wasted. Still I don't understand which emergency could rise the need for colloidal silver. (If you think about using it as disinfectant, it won't work on viruses, just in case you think about that).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a resistor. You have 54V so 13K would limit it to about 4mA. Whether it gets up to 1mA or not would depend on the solution conductivity.

Distilled water is a pretty good insulator but once it gets some ionic contamination it will conduct much more. You could use a multimeter and a 10K pot in series with a resistor of a few K to fool with it.

Comment: Wouldn't \$4\:\text{km}\$ of #40 silver wire do the trick? ;)

Comment: @jonk don’t know why I didn’t think of that. Reminds me of the Calutrons used in the Manhattan project-13,000 tons of silver borrowed from the US Treasury.

Comment: I hadn't read about that before. Interesting story. Now I'm annoyed at my lack of knowledge about colloidal silver. I know that silver is insoluble in water, so it must be going into tiny particles (if a suspension.) But why would it? And what about particle size control (and safety vs particle size if consumed?) It could form a hydroxide (as water has that) but the reaction energy would direct that towards Ag2O, which I think is black and would be visible. Impurities could explain a lot, though I've no idea how good that might be for consumption. Anyway, I need to read more, I guess.

Comment: I’ll see if I can find that type of wire available.  In a pinch however, it might be easy to find a silver bar or coin.  I am trying to assemble my idea based on things I could find readily in a home or office.  Like what resistor to rob off a computer board and soldering, How I might arrange battery types. I have a great grasp of CS on how to use it and the benefits and how to make it properly.  I want to apply some of that IQ into the electronics of it.  By the end of the day, my goal is to learn how to read and understand the schematic of the simulated circuit provided.

Comment: @mrindianajones Well, understanding schematics is a whole different thing. (Good thing, just a different thing.) If all you really want is to control current through a bit of silver (silver has the lowest resistivity of any elemental metal at room temp) then the simplest way to do this is to make the highest voltage you can tolerate and use a resistor value of R=V/I (approximately.) It's wasteful. But it works. (The real equation is more like R+rs=V/I, where rs is the silver resistance. But that's probably very small.)

Answer (score 0):

Current limiter ~2.3mA:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOWhRI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>